# apache cannot redirect to custom error page in SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, httpd.conf

i've stumbled in an error, while redirecting 404 http response to our custom 404 page. This redirection works in http (port 80) but it didn't work in https (port 443)

this is our sites config:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

## SSL config ##


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

###redirect permanent####
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/proxyhost/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/proxyhost_ssl_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/proxyhost_ssl_requests.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

    ProxyPass /context1/ http://ip:port/context1/
    ProxyPass /context2/ http://ip:port//context2/

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/proxyhost/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

any idea why https redirection didn't work here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

Solution: Add the same ServerName value for both http and https virtualhost